# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is my first project in React. I've got this element `<DragDropContext onDragEnd={(result) => this.HandleOnDragEnd(result)}>`and after completing the drag it calls the following function where I get the error:

```
    HandleOnDragEnd = (result) =>
    {
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { "Content-type":"application/json",
                       "Accept":"application/json",
                       "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br" }
        };
        fetch(url, requestOptions)
            .then(function(response){
                if(!response.ok)
                {
                    return response.statusText;
                }
                else{
                    const items = [...this.state.sets];
                    const itemReordered = items.splice(result.source.index, 1);
                    items.splice(result.destination.index, 0, itemReordered);
                    this.setState({sets: items});
                }
            })
    }
```

The issue happens within the else statement. For some reason it thinks that this.state is undefined. So far everywhere I've checked it just says to either bind `this` with the function within the constructor or to use an arrow function which I have, so I don't understand what's causing this issue.

**UPDATE 1**

I'm able to `console.log(this.state.sets);` at the start of the function so my only assumption would be that it's not defined within the .then function for some reason. Is there a way around it?

Comment: You used an arrow function for `handleOnDrageEnd`, but the promise handler is a plain `function`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `function(){}` instead of arrow function (`() => {}`).

This way the function is not inheriting the `this` from your class component, so `this` is `undefined`.

> You can read more about arrow function and `this` [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#description) .

---

Convert your `function(){}` into an arrow function `() => {}`
or
`.bind()` your function using `this` as param (like `function(){}.bind(this)`)
in order to solve the problem.